# How to wait for response in $.post jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

PHP returns value  with 1-2 second delay jQuery.post doesn't wait for response.

How do you think, is it possible to fix that problem and wait for response?

```
    $.post( sSource, aoData, function (data) {    
        oCache.lastJson = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);
        if ( oCache.iCacheLower != oCache.iDisplayStart )
        {
            data.aaData.splice( 0, oCache.iDisplayStart-oCache.iCacheLower );
        }
        data.aaData.splice( oCache.iDisplayLength, data.aaData.length );
         abc(oCache);
        fnCallback(data); 
    },"json" );
```

*Note* the same function with get works well

```
    $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
        /* Callback processing */
        oCache.lastJson = jQuery.extend(true, {}, json);

        if ( oCache.iCacheLower != oCache.iDisplayStart )
        {
            json.aaData.splice( 0, oCache.iDisplayStart-oCache.iCacheLower );
        }
        json.aaData.splice( oCache.iDisplayLength, json.aaData.length );

        fnCallback(json)
    } );
```

Comment: Maybe the request just fails?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't wait for a response"? I'm pretty sure it does--perhaps you're not getting the response you think you are or should be getting?

Comment: @gdoron no it doesn't. I see result after 1-2 second in Firebug

Comment: @epic_syntax: And, also in Firebug, is your callback function executing before the response?  I suspect it isn't, and that something else is wrong.  Put breakpoints in the code to see when it actually executes.  Calls to `alert()` are also helpful for such debugging.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$.post is asynchronous, you need to use $.ajax and set async to false, that way you will be able to wait for the response.
You can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: All the shorthand ajax methods - `.load()`, `.get()`, `.post()`, `getJSON()` and `getScript()` - are asynchronous. As such, it can be said that they all "wait for the server response". AFAIK, only `.ajax()` itself, with `asynch:false`, is not asynchronous but should never be used as it is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: So, what is the solution?

Comment: @JoeTidee use Promise 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise